# Get the date range for the current month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, delphi-7

I would like to create a SQL statement to later be used in my code, that gets the date range for the current month.

Example:  This is August, so the date range would be

```
StartDate = 08/01/11
EndDate = 08/31/11
```

however, if it was February

```
StartDate = 02/01/11
EndDate = 02/28/11

Select * 
from mytable 
where (check_date >= StartDate) AND (check_date <= EndDate)
```

thanks for any help you may be able to give

Comment: One issue with using the last day of the month is that you need to be sure that `check_date` never occurs later than 12 am. If it can, then it's better to use `check_date < StartDateOfNextMonth`.

Comment: @dotjoe - I agree.  I could write a white paper on why one should use exclusive end-dates rather than inclusive end-dates.  In this case you end up with `>= 1st August AND < 1st September` which is So Much Easier to do...  (Note: Using this format means that it does NOT matter if the field is always a DATE or if it can be a DATETIME, it works in either case...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The you can find the start of this month with the months-since-zero trick.  The last day of the month is one month later, minus one day:

```
select  dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()),0)
,       dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,-1,getdate()),0))
```

This prints:

```
1-aug-2011    31-aug-2011
```

Comment: It does print the date as 2011-08-01 00:00:00.00 but then the date can be converted to any format wanted.

Comment: Depending on how you use the values, you should indeed increase the end of month to the next day, so the 31-Aug-2011 becomes 1-Sep-2011 because the 31-Aug is the very start of that day at 00:00:00 AM (or midnight if splitting hairs). I inherited some C# code doing a similar query and noticed we were missing events on the last day of the month and I had to add one more day in the query to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed very similar thing, to get month's date range from specific date, which was possible to use in SQL search - that means not only dates must be correct, but time must be from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 if in 24 hour system, but it just matter of displaying DATETIME format, it will work with 12 hours system too.

Maybe it will be useful for someone. This solution is based on Andomar's answer:

```
-- Parameter date, which must be given to this code
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE() -- for testing purposes initializing some date

-- Declare @from and to date range variables
DECLARE @from DATETIME
DECLARE @to DATETIME

-- This code line is based on Andomar's answer
SET @from = DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month, 0, @date),0) 

-- Just simply to variable @from adds 1 month, minus 1 second
SET @to = DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, @date))

-- Result
SELECT @from, @to
```

You will get result like *2012.01.01 00:00:00 - 2012.01.31 23:59:59*.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the month range just for checking if "check_date" belongs to a specific month, you maybe can use a condition like

```
month(Check_date) = @Month and year(Check_date) = @Year
```

Comment: Although simpler/shorter, this does mean that you get table scans rather than index seeks (Not SARGable).  Performing operations on the field being searched generally destroys such performance.  (Short Code != Efficient Code)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns the end date for the given date.

So the function you can pass the start date and it will be like this

```
WHEN(MONTH(@date) IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12)) THEN 31
WHEN(MONTH(@date) IN (4, 6, 9, 11)) THEN 30
ELSE 
    CASE 
       WHEN (YEAR(@date) % 4 = 0
       AND YEAR(@date) % 100 != 0)
       OR (YEAR(@date) % 400  = 0)
       THEN 29
        ELSE 28
END
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against implementing date rules such as these, rely on the date functions already implemented.

Comment: Don't know about library support for different calendars, but this only works for the (proleptic) Gregorian calendar.  If your data happens to be for some regional calendar (or even just Julian), this will _not_ work as expected.

Comment: -1. This is wrong. If the DB implements the functionality needed, why rely on doing it yourself? (Don't reinvent the wheel.)